# All Outbound Traffic Uses IPV6

Tags: linux-networking, ip, ipv6, ipv4, telnet

I have a Debian 10 server which has postfix installed, each time I try to send outbound mail traffic, the server uses IPV6 over IPV4. This causes postfix to log **Connection timed out**.

I have tried sending packets to google SMTP server using telnet, whenever I run the command `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` the terminal delays for some seconds and then outputs

```
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c06::1a...
Trying 173.194.76.27...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Please I have no clue on what is happening.

Comment: Using IPv6 over IPv4 is normal and expected. This is how the Internet works. You have a different problem. Most likely your provider has blocked outgoing SMTP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks so much, I noticed my provider blocks port 25, 465, and 587 by default and I have opened a ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many hosting providers block outgoing SMTP for new customers. There is usually a process by which you can have it unblocked or otherwise send mail; contact the provider for specifics.